# Can I write instance or class method inside if condition?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Can I write something like this inside model ?

```
if true
  def instance_method
  end

  def class_method
  end
end
```

Comment: It is totally valid Ruby code. If you want to know if it does what you are trying to accomplish, we need more information. Some context would help.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know if statements do not introduce scope in Ruby 1.9.2 so you can use statements like that

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you desire?

```
if true
    my_object.instance_eval do
        def my_instance_method

        end
    end

    my_object.class_eval do
        def my_class_eval

        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use also:

```
   if true
    class << self
      def first_method
      end

      def second_method
      end
    end
   end
```

but it would be better when you will post some real code here